# Что делать если проект на одном пк работает, а на другом абсолютно такой же нет?

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome, frontend, веб-сервер, браузер

Разворачиваю проект. На одном персональном компьютере все хорошо, на другом проделав все действия что и на первом ничего не работает(клонировал репозиторий, установил npm пакеты, запустил). В консоли все хорошо и ошибок нет. В браузере он не видит даже структуру проекта, а лишь пустую папку.

В консоли все хорошо и идентично рабочему проекту.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлю еще что в первом проекте сразу идет переадресация, у меня же она не происходит. Хотя проект идентичный.
Пробовал отключить проверку сетевых файлов, и даже это не сработало.

Comment: маловато данных. Вы думаете, что мы Вас поймём по словам "проект" и "репозиторий". За этим может скрываться что угодно - от статического сайта до своего веб-сервера. Добавьте подробностей,к аск будто вы общаетесь с не очень понятливыми людьми?

Comment: "Ниччего непонятно, но оччень интересно!" :) Что именно вы делаете? Какие команды, что пишет в ответ? Проанализируйте, вчитайтесь в вывод комманд.

Comment: Ну например расходятся версии языков. Или серверов. Или серверных языков

Comment: Я добавил, но я не думаю что это что то изменит, на пк использую впн для внешних апи, в проекте встроенный прокси для запросов к апи.